# Python -> OpenCV module cannot load

Tags: python, opencv, compatibility

I already have

```
Python 2.7.13
numpy 1.7 for Python 2.7
```

Already downloaded OpenCV 3.2 and OpenCV 2.4.13.
Copied cv2.pyd to /Lib/site-packages.
Nothing imports cv2.
Already tried copying cv2.pyd from both versions of OpenCV and their x64 and x86.
Still nothing.
Numpy is working though.

All are giving me the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 Application.
```

Any ideas?

PS: I'm quite new to Python and OpenCV.

Comment: If you are using Anaconda, see [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41199408/install-opencv-in-anaconda3?rq=1)

Comment: Try using Anaconda